# Likelihood ratio test in R

Tags: r, testing, finance, log-likelihood

I have 2 linear models I have run in R

```
model_1_regression <- lm(model_1$ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ model_1$Rm.Rf + 
                         model_1$SMB + 
                         model_1$HML + 
                         model_1$MOM, 
                         na.action=na.exclude)
```

and

```
model_1_mom_1_regression <- lm(model_1_mom_1$ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ model_1_mom_1$Rm.Rf + 
                               model_1_mom_1$SMB + 
                               model_1_mom_1$HML + 
                               model_1_mom_1$MOM +
                               model_1_mom_1$mom_to_add,
                               na.action=na.omit)
```

and I would like to run a likelihood ratio test to see if the additional factor added is significant. How can I do this, and how can I interpret the results shown?

Many thanks

Comment: This could be useful: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lmtest/versions/0.9-36/topics/lrtest or this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r

Answer (score 2):

To compare nested models, you can use different criteria including p-value from LRT or ANOVA, Adjusted-R<sup>2</sup>, AIC, BIC and so on. LRT and ANOVA would yield the same outcome in terms of detecting a difference. Briefly, obtaining a p-value below the chosen significance level from these two tests indicates sufficient evidence in favor of rejecting the null hypothesis claiming the two models are equivalent. I recommend you search for additional information and the theory.

Your code includes different data (*model_1* & *model_1_mom_1*) and `NA` treatments (*na.exclude* & *na.omit*), which makes me question whether your models are actually **nested** or not. Please make sure that you are fitting the models using the same data by supplying the same data set and `NA` treatment option to both functions. Then you can use `anova`:

```
# refactored your code and supplied the same data & na.action

reduced_model <- lm(formula = ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ 
                      Rm.Rf + 
                      SMB + 
                      HML + 
                      MOM,
                    data = df,
                    na.action=na.omit)

full_model <- lm(formula = ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ 
                   Rm.Rf + 
                   SMB + 
                   HML + 
                   MOM +
                   mom_to_add,
                 data = df,
                 na.action=na.omit)

# based on f-test
anova(reduced_model, full_model)

# based on chi-square test
anova(reduced_model, full_model, test = "LRT")
```

Note that there are other functions in R for running LRT such as `lrtest` but it computes the test statistic in a slightly different way. You can adopt one of them depending on your context. Please refer here for more information:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155474/r-why-does-lrtest-not-match-anovatest-lrt

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the log-likelihood ratio test can be implemented with `R` for nested models:

```
set.seed(123)
# generated dummy data
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(
    Rm.Rf = runif(n), 
    SMB = rnorm(n),
    HML = runif(n),
    MOM = rnorm(n),
    mom_to_add = runif(n)
)
df$ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 <- 2*df$Rm.Rf - 36*df$SMB + 5*df$HML + 20*df$MOM + 0.5*df$mom_to_add + rnorm(n)

nested <- lm(formula = ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ 
                       Rm.Rf + SMB + HML + MOM,
                       data = df,
                       na.action=na.omit)
complex <- lm(formula = ff4f_actual_excess_return_month1 ~ 
                        Rm.Rf + SMB + HML + MOM + mom_to_add,
                 data = df,
                 na.action=na.omit)

teststat <- -2 * (as.numeric(logLik(nested))-as.numeric(logLik(complex)))
teststat
# [1] 5.656315
p.val <- pchisq(teststat, df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)     # teststat ~ χ2(1) by Wilks theorem
p.val
# [1] 0.01739263
```

We can plot the results obtained above and notice that the null hypothesis H0 can be rejected, so that we can conclude that the complex model explains the data better.

```
alpha <- 0.05
x <- seq(0, 6, 0.01)
plot(x, dchisq(x, df=1), type='l', lwd=2, xlab='', ylab='')
abline(v = qchisq(1-alpha, df=1), col='red', lwd=2, lty=2)
points(teststat, 0, col='green', pch=19, cex=2)
legend('topright', c("χ2(1)", "α=0.05", "tstat"), 
        col = c('black', 'red', 'green'), 
        pch = c(NA, NA, 19), lwd = c(2, 2, NA), lty = c(1, 2, NA))
```

[image]